# how to create a costume layout for json data returned from mysql database for UTF-8 characters in php

Tags: php, mysql, json, utf-8

I am trying to create a json representation of mysql data in a restful webservice using php. my returned json should look something like this:

```
"worktypes" :
[
    {
        "id" : "1",
        "name" : "نوع 1",
        "isactive" : "true"
    },
    {
        "id" : "2",
        "name" : "نوع 2",
        "isactive" : "false"
    }
]
```

one of my options was to iterate through my result records and `echo` each line by hand. It was working until I reached `utf8` characters shown above (like 'نوع 1') and instead of ending up with something like `\u00d9\u0086\u00d9\u0088\u00d8\u00b9` I got unreadable symbols like `ÃÂÃÂÃÂ¹ ÃÂ§ÃÂÃÂ`.

If I could use `json_encode` somehow to create this layout, it would automatically solve this problem;But I don't know how to create such a structure in php that its json_encoded string represents my desired layout.

My other option is to somehow encode these characters myself. But I don't know how to do that either.

Could anyone help me with my problem?

UPDATE: I use a simple `echo` in my webservice when I get unusual characters like :

```
$result = array("1" => "نوع 1")
echo $result;

//results in 'ÙÙØ¹ 1' when called using webservice
```

Comment: Post your code, we need to see where you are getting this "ÃÂÃÂÃÂ¹ ÃÂ§ÃÂÃÂ".

Comment: To avoid the `\u....`, `json_encode($s, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)`

Comment: when I use `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` I get unreadable symbols again

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent PHP array to what you have given is:

```
$x = array(
    "worktypes" => array( 
        array(
            "id" => "1",
            "name" => "نوع 1",
            "isactive" => "true"
        ),
        array(
            "id" => "2",
            "name" => "نوع 2",
            "isactive" => "false"
        )
    )
);
```

You can then use `json_encode`.

Note that you may still see escaped characters, but the browser should be able to handle unescaping them when it parses the JSON.